# Ошибка CORS при POST запросе reddit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors

Делаю app через CRA (клиент реддита).

При авторизации запрашиваю все интересующие доступы согласной документации. Скрин редиректа в реддит ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле client_id все тоже корректно (убрал чтоб сделать скрин).

Все get запросы проходят корректно (получение комментов, получение списков постов и тп), а post запросы валятся с ошибкой CORS.

Что хочу за запросы прокидывать: скрытие комментария/поста, изменение рейтинга и тп.
Все запросы делаются исходя из доки реддита: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_comment

Код thunkа на скрытие поста следующий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем не прав?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063796/1016033

Comment: Alexey Ten, к сожалению такой вариант запроса так же не срабатывает. Скорректировал https://oauth.reddit.com + урл на то, как предлагали в предлагаемой статье.
Та же ошибка вылетает